# Problem to save render jpeg with maxscript

Tags: save, render, 3dsmax, maxscript

I am making a script to automate the process of render multiple .max files. I almost finished what I pretend to achive, the only problem is that I don't know how to save the render image by maxscript. I tried several ways I foud on the internet but none of them works.

```
studioFile = getOpenFileName caption: "Select the Studio"

loadMaxFile studioFile

folderPath = getSavePath caption: "Select the Folder with the Assets to Render"
maxPath = folderPath + "\*.max"
maxFiles = getFiles maxPath

renderPath = getSavePath caption: "Select the Render Folder"

for current in maxFiles do(
        
    xrefs.addNewXRefFile current
    currentName = getFilenameFile current
    print currentName
    
    for c in cameras where classof c != Targetobject do(
        
        render camera:c output: ("E:\\MUVA\\Renders\\" + currentName + "_" + c.name + "_" + ".jpeg")
        
    )
    
    xrefs.deleteAllXRefs()
   
)
```

This is how my code is for now and explaining it:

- First, I made a Dialog Box for the user to select what I am calling "Studio" that is a scene with lighting and cameras ready for the render and then open it;
- Second, is another Dialog Box for the user to select the folder where the .max files to render are;
- Thrid, is another Dialog Box for the user to select the folder where he wish to save the renders;
- Then I made a loop where through a list, the program will add the .max file to render as a xref scene and rigth after that get the name of the .max file to use in the saving.
- The next and final loop is to get a render from each camera in the scene and then save but the problem is that the image is not been saved in the folder selected.

I really don't know more what to do. So, I would be very grateful if somebody could help me with this.

PS.: The selected folder to save the renders is not been used in the output of the render by now because I was testing putting all the path to the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MAXScript reference](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-9175301C-13E6-488B-ABA6-D27CD804B205), the parameter for filename is `outputfile:`. In your case the line would be:

```
render camera:c outputfile:("E:\\MUVA\\Renders\\" + currentName + "_" + c.name + "_" + ".jpeg")
```

There's also another way: you can save the bitmap object that the `render()` function returns:

```
bm = render camera:c
bm.filename = "E:\\MUVA\\Renders\\" + currentName + "_" + c.name + "_" + ".jpeg"
save bm
```

The directory must exist for any of these methods to work, so you may want to create it before your loop:

```
makeDir "E:\\MUVA\\Renders" all:true
```

Comment: OMG! I feel so stupid. Thanks, man. You saved me. There is just one more thing. I'm using the Corona to render. In Render Elements (in the render dialog setup when I activate the Corona) I add a CTexmap to generate a wireframe jpeg too. I need that the wireframe images goes to the same folder and that they change their name to the respective asset, just like with the normal renders. There's a way to do this?